# Convert DFS List to Tree

Tags: javascript

Considering the following tree:

```
[
  { 
    id: 0,
    children: [
      { 
        id: 1,
        id: 2 
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    children: [
      { id: 4 },
      { id: 5,
        children: [
          {
            id: 6,
            id: 7 
          }
        ] 
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And the following list generated by a DFS walker:

```
[
  { id: 0, isLeaf: false, nestingLevel: 0 },
  { id: 1, isLeaf: true, nestingLevel: 1 },
  { id: 2, isLeaf: true, nestingLevel: 1 },
  { id: 3, isLeaf: false, nestingLevel: 0 },
  { id: 4, isLeaf: true, nestingLevel: 1 },
  { id: 5, isLeaf: false, nestingLevel: 1 },
  { id: 6, isLeaf: true, nestingLevel: 2 },
  { id: 7, isLeaf: true, nestingLevel: 2 }
];
```

How can I restore the original tree from the generated list assuming that we can have more than two nesting levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, you want objects with a singel `id` property, you could take a helper array for same levels and store along with the object an assignment to the following sub level.

```js
var data = [{ id: 0, isLeaf: false, nestingLevel: 0 }, { id: 1, isLeaf: true, nestingLevel: 1 }, { id: 2, isLeaf: true, nestingLevel: 1 }, { id: 3, isLeaf: false, nestingLevel: 0 }, { id: 4, isLeaf: true, nestingLevel: 1 }, { id: 5, isLeaf: false, nestingLevel: 1 }, { id: 6, isLeaf: true, nestingLevel: 2 }, { id: 7, isLeaf: true, nestingLevel: 2 }],
    result = [],
    levels = [result];

data.forEach(({ id, isLeaf, nestingLevel }) => levels[nestingLevel].push(isLeaf
    ? { id }
    : { id, children: levels[nestingLevel + 1] = [] }
));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A slightly different version without using `isLeaf` and storing without `children` property.

This property is only generated for nested levels in necessary.

```js
var data = [{ id: 0, nestingLevel: 0 }, { id: 1, nestingLevel: 1 }, { id: 2, nestingLevel: 1 }, { id: 3, nestingLevel: 0 }, { id: 4, nestingLevel: 1 }, { id: 5, nestingLevel: 1 }, { id: 6, nestingLevel: 2 }, { id: 7, nestingLevel: 2 }],
    result = [],
    levels = [result];

data.forEach(({ id, nestingLevel: l }) => {
    if (!levels[l]) levels[l] = levels[l - 1][levels[l - 1].length - 1].children = [];
    levels[l].push({ id });
    levels.length = l + 1;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you Nina, this is exactly what I was looking for!
The last bit missing is to not generate a `children` property key if it's a leaf node, but this should be an easy task 

Comment: Sweet! This is perfect ❤️